# PHP loop through array and execute statements

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code for inserting prepared values into MySQL with PDO, but am looking for a way to tidy it up with a loop, to avoid repetition:

```
// PDO connect
    $pdo = new PDO($sqldsn, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqlopt);

    // Prepare query
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("$query");

    // Cycle through additional values
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
    $sqlarray[] = $arg;
    }

    // Execute query with values
    $count = count($sqlarray);

    if ($count == "2") { $stm->execute([$sqlarray[1]]); } 
    if ($count == "3") { $stm->execute([$sqlarray[1], $sqlarray[2]]); }
    if ($count == "4") { $stm->execute([$sqlarray[1], $sqlarray[2], $sqlarray[3] ]); }
    if ($count == "5") { $stm->execute([$sqlarray[1], $sqlarray[2], $sqlarray[3], $sqlarray[4] ]); } 
    if ($count == "6") { $stm->execute([$sqlarray[1], $sqlarray[2], $sqlarray[3], $sqlarray[4], $sqlarray[5] ]); }
    if ($count == "7") { $stm->execute([$sqlarray[1], $sqlarray[2], $sqlarray[3], $sqlarray[4], $sqlarray[5], $sqlarray[6] ]); }


    // Fetch all
    $result = $stm->fetchAll();

    // Return result    
    return $result;
```

I've tried looping like this, but I don't get any results (other than the number of array entries):

```
    for ($i = 1; $i<=$count; $i++){
        echo $i;
        $stm->execute([$sqlarray[$i]]);
    }
```

I also tried to construct the sections using eval(), but understand that this isn't a safe idea for security reasons.

I just need it to cycle through as per my code, but without having to specify each number of possible prepared ? values.
Can anyone help?  Sorry for the newb question, but I'm currently learning PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need any loops at all.

You should be able to get the results you want with just a few lines of code;

```
$pdo = new PDO($sqldsn, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqlopt);

// Prepare query
$stm = $pdo->prepare($query);

$arr = array_values(func_get_args()); //gets rid of your foreach loop
array_shift($arr); //gets rid of first element of array

$stm->execute($arr);

return $stm->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Great, that works perfectly, and with succinct code!  Many thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the first element with `array_shift`:

```
// PDO connect
    $pdo = new PDO($sqldsn, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqlopt);

    // Prepare query
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("$query");

    // Cycle through additional values
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
    $sqlarray[] = $arg;
    }

    // Execute query with values
    $arr   = $sqlarray;  // Make a copy
    $first = array_shift($arr);  // Remove the first element
    $stm->execute($arr);  // Execute query with resulting array

    // Fetch all
    $result = $stm->fetchAll();

    // Return result    
    return $result;
```

Comment: Be careful using `array_shift()` with large arrays as each time an element is added or removed to the start of an array, the process for re-indexing all the other keys isn't efficient on larger arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  That works, but grumpy's answer avoids the loop altogether.  :)

Comment: you're welcome!  I had simply tried to address the repetition.  Didn't realize you wanted to remove the `foreach` loop as well.  But yes, @grumpy's solution is more elegant